# Apache CXF 2.6.8 compatibility with JDK 7

Tags: java, cxf

Is Apache CXF 2.6.8 compatible with JDK 1.7 ? If not then which version work with JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about CXF 2.6.8 but I've worked with CXF 2.7.5, I didn't face any problem with JDK1.7

Answer (score 0):

Based on CXF response, I am currently running CXF 2.6.8 on JDK 8, and so far no issues.

Of course, it is advisable to upgrade to latest version 2.7.9 for version 2.

Excerpt from CXF Website

> **Can CXF run with JDK 1.5**?
>   Yes for CXF 2.6.x and older. Keep in mind though that Java 2 SE 5.0 with JDK 1.5 has reached end of life (EOL).
>  CXF 2.7.x no longer supports Java 5. In order to upgrade to 2.7.x, you must be using Java 6 (or newer).
>   
> There are no more planned releases for the 2.6.x series of CXF that will support Java 5. Users are strongly encouraged to start moving to Java 7 and to start migrating to newer versions of CXF.